Stuck in tty mode
I am stuck in tty mode in Ubuntu. Can't use apt install commands because internet does not work. How do I back to gui mode?
Pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7 to switch directly to GUI mode does not work
Ubuntu version 22.04

You find GUI at Ctrl-Alt-F2 nowadays.
